# Creating shared library for dependent C programs for using in JNA

Tags: c, compilation, shared-libraries, jna, dynamic-library

I am new to JNA and C, So I am facing trouble creating shared library for dependent C programs.
I already have tried with only 1 C program.

Basically my codes is like this:

file1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include header.h

void function1(unsigned char *parm){

      // --relevant code

      function 2(parm)
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef    header_H
#define    header_H
unsigned char name;
void function2(unsigned char*);
#endif
```

file2.c

```
#include header.h
void function2(unsigned char*) {
// relevant codes
 printf (" hello");

}
```

I am using windows terminal for compiling and creating the shared library.
I have to use function1 () in java program through JNA/JNI.

Also as it is a project requirement, I cannot change the C files or headers.

During compilation I am able to create (.o files) for each of the prog.

```
gcc -c -Wall   file1.c file2.c
```

-> When making shared library for prog1

```
 gcc -shared -o newlib.dll file1.o
```

It is throwing error of **undefined reference** of prog2.

```
.c:(.text+0x16a): undefined reference to `function2()
```

-> When creating share library like this

```
 gcc -shared -o newlib.dll file1.o file2.o
```

Its throwing error like

```
multiple definition of char name;
```

-> I don't know how to create shared library including both programs.

Can someone share some resources to look upon.

Comment: A minimal, reproducible example would make it easier for people to give a helpful answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The code snippets shown would not even compile without errors (e.g. the first parameter of fprintf would be of type FILE * and not a string). Also, please include the exact error text in the error question. Otherwise the question is hard to answer.

Comment: The actual codes are from project, so I just made a dummy codes. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the error `multiple definition of char name`
It's because both `file1.c` and `file2.c` are include `header.h`, so `unsigned char name` is defined twice.
The header file should looks like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
// your code
#endif // HEADER_H
```

Comment: Yeah the header file  has #ifndef and #endif tag , but still the error is same

Comment: @AlokRanjanSwain I followed your step, it compiled success. Do you recompile your files?

Comment: I am not able to create shared library.

Comment: @AlokRanjanSwain What error do you get? I fixed some compile error such as add quotes in include file. BTW, why not use Visual Studio.

Comment: I am getting multiple declaration error on the command {gcc -shared -o newlib.dll file1.o file2.o}

Comment: Are you able to create shared library in {dll/so} format in vs code ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above by creating shared library for file2, then creating object file of file1 by linking the created shared library. Then we can easily create share lib for file1 also using its object file.
Codes will be like

```
gcc -c -Wall -fPIC file2.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so file2.o
gcc -c -nostartfiles -Wl,--entry=function1 -L. -Wall file1.c -lfoo
gcc -shared -L. -o newLib.so file1.o -lfoo
```

As I don't have main function I have to use -nostartfiles flag and explicitly defining entry point.